# Converting Longitude & Latitude to X Y on a map

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

What would be the algorithm for calculating the corresponding XY point in the map with a given Longitude / Latitude pair?

Comment: You need to specify the projection.  Is X Y flat earth?  Mercator?  UTM?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). It shows some important formulas when working with latitude and longitude.

Comment: I don't think this link will help.  The formula in the link are for lat/lon great circle calculations not projections.